# Attribute programming in C#

Tags: c#, attributes

I am new to Attribute programming. Not sure if i am asking the right question or not.

I have an abstract base class (AbstarctBase) and two drived classes Derived1 and Derived2. 
My AbstartBase class have two methods Method1 and Method2.

Is it possible to use attribute programming so that when I do this

```
AbstractBase ab= new Derived1();
```

I only get access to `Method1` and when I use `Derived2` class I only get access to `Method2`.

Is this possible. If yes, then can you please give me an example to start with.

Comment: What is "attribute programming"? Anyway, "No" - not like that. This because `AbstractBase` has *both* methods defined (as such, *all* derived classes inherit those methods). If you only want it in a particular derived class, declare it there. If you just wish to keep external code from seeing the base methods, you may be able to use sufficient visibility modifiers - e.g. `protected`.

Comment: In your situation an interface would be better, in this way you can declare public the methods you want to be visible and prívate the hidden ones

Answer (score 0):

I think you are linking two different concepts of Inhetitance or Polymorphism and Attributes. In case of your problem what you can do is you can make an Inerface having a method and implement that differently in your deriving classes than use polymorphism to invoke that implementation that you require. For example

```
    public interface IBase
    {
      void Foo();
    }

    public class Derived1: IBase
    {
      public void Foo()
      {
        //Print Derived 1
      }
    }

    public class Derived2: IBase
    {
      public void Foo()
      {
        //Print Derived 2
      }
    }

   public class Program
   {
    public static void Main(String args[])
    {
      IBase base=new Derived1();
      base.Foo();//This prints Derived 1
      base=new Derived2();
      base.Foo();//This prints Derived 2
    }
   }
```

Where as Attributes in C# are used to attach metadata to your classes or class members, as well as when applying a common behaviour without having to implement a certain interface for each unit that shares the behaviour. They are used like this

```
    [MyAttribute]
    public class MyClass
    {
      //Class body
    }
```

You need to call the attribute by using GetCustomAttribute() method otherwise it will do nothing. For more information on attribute please refer this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2933/Attributes-in-C
Hope this hepls you.